# wordpress nginx 404 page

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404

I faced an issue. After migration of current website from LAMP to LEMP I faced an issue that wordpress 404 page is not working. Config will be provided below.
When I'm trying to reach non existing page I'm getting 301 to homepage instead of 404.
I've read a lot of about similar issues but nothing helped.
I assume that problem is in this line:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Nginx is checking if static file exists, after that it checks if directory exists, and only then in runs index.php. As I understood index.php is not running, after checking directory Nginx redirects to homepage.

Do you have any ideas?
My config (I use ajenti for server administration, so config is generated via ajenti)

```
#AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED - DO NO EDIT!
server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name server.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/servercom.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/servercom.error.log;

    root /srv/server.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #Redirect non-https traffic to https
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    # Global restrictions configuration file.
    # Designed to be included in any server {} block.
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
    # Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }


    location / {
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
    # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    error_page 404  /404.html;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    #Yoast SEO Sitemaps
    location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*).x(m|s)l$ {
    ## this redirects sitemap.xml to /sitemap_index.xml
    rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
    ## this makes the XML sitemaps work
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
    ## The following lines are optional for the premium extensions
    ## News SEO
    rewrite ^/news-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
    ## Local SEO
    rewrite ^/locations.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
    rewrite ^/geo-sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
    ## Video SEO
    rewrite ^/video-sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=video last;
    }


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        alias /srv/webspace.by;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/ajenti-v-php7.0-fcgi-webspaceby-php7.0-fcgi-0.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try commenting out `error_page 404  /404.html;`?